# What should I learn in Java SE before proceeding to Java EE?

Tags: java

Currently, I've learned the following in Java SE:

- Logical Operations
- Loops
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism
- Abstract Classes
- Interface

I'm currently learning Strings, Characters and Regular Expressions. What are things that I should learn before proceeding to Java EE?

Answer (score 4):

You might already know this but they are one in the same except that Java EE is the enterprise version, meaning more advanced features such as servlets.

I would say learn everything in SE (core) java before going into the Enterprise Edition. Now it's not enough to learn something to know it, you should *understand* it as well.

For example: Why does Java have **Multiple Inheritance** in terms of implementing multiple interfaces rather than extending multiple abstract classes like C++?

**OR**

Why would you use and Abstract class over an interface and vice versa?

I'd say gather as much of an in-depth understanding to the core aspects of java before tackling the advanced topics. Also conquer data-structures, Object Orient Principles, Generics, Threading, annotations, and anything else that may envelop the basic understanding of java. Now of course you don't have to know all the intricacies of java just have somewhat of a basic understanding.

Scour forums and **EXPERIMENT**! Code non-stop until your fingers bleed. Lastly always ask questions to what you have learned!!!!

> Any fool can know. The point is to understand.
>   -Anonymous

Comment: `Any fool can know. The point is to understand. -Albert Einstein` Extreme nitpicking: [I don't think Einstein ever said / wrote it](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Albert_Einstein).

Comment: So in other words, my Einstein poster is lying to me?

Comment: :) If it is, you should blame the [21 books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22any+fool+can+know%22+einstein&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) that attribute the quote to Einstein, not your poster... Posters are fun!